# Running Clang-query on objective-c files that import Foundation

Tags: c++, clang, llvm-clang, foundation, clang-query

I am trying to use clang-query to run matches against obj-c files that import Foundation but its not working, After building `clang-query` by moving it to the `tools/extra` folder, I run it using this command:

`./clang-query MyClass.m --  -extra-arg-before "-isysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.1.sdk"`

But I'm getting this error:

```
 fatal error: 'stdarg.h' file not found
#include <stdarg.h>
```

How should I be running `clang-query` to analyse my objective-c sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research I found out that the right approach is to use `libTooling` based tools. As stated in their documentation:

```
Clang Tooling needs a compilation database to figure out specific build options for each file. Currently it can create a compilation database from the compile_commands.json file
```

For Xcode projects, this file can be generated like this:

`xcodebuild -project PROJECT_NAME.xcodeproj | xcpretty -r json-compilation-database --output compile_commands.json`

you will need to install the `xcpretty` gem. (`gem install xcpretty`)

Source: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/HowToSetupToolingForLLVM.html

**UPDATE:**
IF like me, you are having issues with the `compile_commands.json` file generated from xcodebuild logs, just pass this commands to your binary:

```
-mios-simulator-version-min=10.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk -isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.00/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
```

You might need to update some of the parameters based on your system configuration but this is working fine for me currently.